# How to set action of UILabel in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I have a UITableView in ViewController and 3 UILabel in it with a Prototype Cell labeled Date, Party and Amount. Now situation is that i want whenever a user tapped on a UILabel, say Date, it shows all records from Database table for particular Date or if User tapped on Party Label then All transactions of particular party will be shown. So please help me in getting this. How could i do this..

Comment: Why don't use UIButton instead of UILabel? and actions for those buttons

Comment: Add Tap Gestures for every labels

Comment: i m new in swift or in Coding. Can You Guys Post Sample Code to do this. i don't want to shift to UIButton from UILabel. Thanks

Comment: Okay i will @Aakash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many to do the same.

1. You can use button without any border or background image. Just give simple text to button and it would look like label. Add action to the button.
2. You can use `UIGestureRecognizers` for the same. You can add Gesture Recognizer directly to all UILabel separately as explained by @LalitKumar. .
3. You can also add  Gesture Recognizer to your Table View and access all its subviews in your UIGesture Recognizer Action .

Add Gesture Recognizer in `viewDidLoad` as

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Yourcontroller.handleTap))
    yourTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    yourTableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Define action for Gesture Recognizer and  get indexpath of cell as well as subviews of cell.

```
func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
     let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: self.tableView)
     if let tapIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) 
     {
         if let tappedCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tapIndexPath) as? UITableViewCell 
          {
             print("Row Selected") // access tapped cell and its subview as
             let touchpoint:CGPoint = gesture.location(in: cell)

                 if cell.datelabel.frame.contains(touchpoint)  {
                       // user tapped date label
                     } elseif cell.imageView.frame.contains(touchpoint) {
                       // user tapped image
                 }
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Yourcontroller.tapLabelFunction))
   yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

 // if you make label on the cell
    cell.yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.yourLabel.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

 func tapLabelFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("label tapped",sender.view!.tag); // for tag

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
yourLabel?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
if ((yourLabel?.gestureRecognizers?.description) == nil) {
                let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(onPeopleName:)))
                tapGesture.delegate = self
                tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
                tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
                yourLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            }
```

**Selector**

```
func tap(onPeopleName gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let lbl: UILabel? = (gesture.view as? UILabel)
        let cell: UITableViewCell? = (lbl?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell)
        let indexPath: IndexPath? = tblViewPracticeDetail.indexPath(for: cell!)
}
```